# PHP – How I can get key name of array

Tags: php, arrays

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
   [1] => Array
      (
         [a] => a
         [b] => b
      )
   [2] => Array
      (
         [a] => c
         [b] => d
      )
   [3] => Array
      (
         [a] => e
         [b] => f
      )
)
```

And I use this code to search definied value:

```
$key = array_search('c', array_column($array, 'a'));
```

But $key not returns '2' (name of key) but '1' (numerically (0, 1, 2, 3)). How I can get name of key?

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = array_search('c', array_map(function($v){return $v['a'];}, $array));
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer to explain what's going on here?